# Website user password verification

Tags: php, mysql, php5, mysqli

I have a login web page where a user enters their email and password and I need to check if:

1. the entered email exists in the DB and
2. the entered password matches the hashed one from the db.

The password in the DB was hashed with

```
$pw = password_hash($_POST["pw"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

and is stored in a `VARCHAR(255)` column. 
Email is set to primary and unique in the DB so there cannot be a duplicate record for this.

To achieve the above I came to the below which works as intended for me. 
However, since I am new to this and because of the double DB connection I was wondering if there is a way to shorten or otherwise improve this code.

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pw = $_POST["pw"]; 

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM Users WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
    echo "Email has not been registered yet";
}else{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT pw FROM Users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $pwHashed = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if(password_verify($pw, $pwHashed["pw"])){
        echo "Password correct";
    }else{
        echo "Password incorrect";
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't need two queries to do this. You can just use your second query, and if it doesn't return any results, report that. Eg:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT pw FROM Users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
    echo "Email has not been registered yet";
}

$pwHashed = $result->fetch_assoc();
if(password_verify($pw, $pwHashed["pw"])){
    echo "Password correct";
}else{
    echo "Password incorrect";
}
```

Other than this, your code looks good. You use prepared statements, so it's secure, and your style is consistent and easy to read. I would probably write `pw` as `password` as it's more readable, but otherwise everything looks good.

Comment: Update: Just a thought on this: The above works great but I noticed that in this case it also returns "Password incorrect" in addition when the email is not registered which might be confusing so I will wrap the last 6 lines in an else statement to only check them if the email actually exists. Does that make sense ?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd mix OOP and procedural functions/methods and since it's possible for `$stmt->get_result()` to return false if something goes wrong, I'd change `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)` to `if(!$result || !$result->num_rows)`. If that occurs either terminate the script, throw an Exception or put the password verification block (which requires `$result` to be a `mysqli_result` object) into an `else` block.

Comment: @keewee279 personally, I would put the whole thing in a function, and then return something (either the result string, or true/false for correct/not correct and throw exception for non-existing email, or have some sort of result object for the string, and then return false for email/pw incorrect and true for correct). And as CD001 said, it would be a good idea to handle errors (otherwise finding bugs will be hard)